# how to fill the value 'None' if the main list value is not presented in sublist

Tags: python

I am trying to create the new nested list from  one main-list and different sub-lists. sub list values are presented in main list.
I have a main list like this.All the sub-list values are unique values of main list.

```py
mainlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

sublist are like this.

```py
sublista = ['a', 'b']
sublistb = ['c', 'd', 'e']
sublistc = ['b', 'e']
sublistd = ['c']
```

I want to get the final list like this.

```py
combined_list = [['yes', 'yes', None, None, None],
                 [None, None, 'yes', 'yes', 'yes'],
                 [None, 'yes', None, None, 'yes'],
                 [None, None, 'yes', None, None]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Are the sublists guaranteed to only have elements from the main list? In other words, can there be `'x'` in the sublists, for example?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Comment: @OneCricketeer all the sbulist values are unique values of main list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension combined with a conditional expression, like this:

```
mainlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
sublista = ['a', 'b']

result = ["yes" if e in sublista else None for e in mainlist]
print(result)
```

But you need to decide how to handle those sublists, since holding each one as a separate variable is not manageable in the long run. Maybe combine them into a single list (of lists)?